# How do I write an object to a file and read it back?

Tags: java, file, serialization

I will need your help because I want to write an object in a file and read it back.

I have a problem with this line of code: `Vehicule result = (Vehicule) read.readObject ();`

```
try {
       List<Vehicule> voiture = new ArrayList<Vehicule>();

       //Write object to file 
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Garage.ser");
       ObjectOutputStream ecriture = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
       System.out.println("\nIci - Ecriture de mon fichier\n");
       ecriture.writeObject(voiture);
       ecriture.close();
       //read object from file
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Garage.ser");
       ObjectInputStream lecture = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        System.out.println("\nIci - Lecture du fichier\n");
        Vehicule result = (Vehicule) lecture.readObject();
        lecture.close();

   }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
       System.out.println("Aucune voitures sauvegardé !");
   }catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem is that you are serializing a `List<Vehicule>` , and attempting to deserialize it as a `Vehicule` .

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're writing a `List<Vehicule>` but read a `Vehicule`.

Comment: Thanks ! How to convert an ArrayList into a String? Is there a method? should I create my own conversion method?

Comment: @Toufik : Just write `List<Vehicule> result = (List<Vehicule>) lecture.readObject();`  then acces the content of your list like e.g `Vehicule firstVehicule = result.get(0);` .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string?rq=1